# How to locate an inputted integer value in a list of an Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

this is my first "problem": Make a program to allow the user to input an integer value to be searched in list3. Your program should display whether the inputted integer value is found in list3, how many of it is in list3, and what are their locations in list3?"

It's almost done, the only problem is that I couldn't follow what is written output given in the example:

List1 : 1  3  2  5  7  8  5  6  9  4

List2 : 2  1  4  3  2  1  4  2  0  2

List3 : 3  4  6  8  9  9  9  8  9  6

Input value to search in List3: 9

The value 9 is in List3!

There are 4 of it in List3.

Located at: list3[4], list3[5], list3[6], list3[8]

and this is my output:

list1 : 1   3   2   5   7   8   5   6   9   4
list2 : 2   1   4   3   2   1   4   2   0   2
list3 : 3   4   6   8   9   9   9   8   9   6

Input value to search in List3: 9

The value 9 is in List3!

There are 4 of it in List 3.

Located at: 4

how do i display the "located at: " like in the example?

*EDITED*
Sorry, I'm kinda new here and in Programming. This is my code:

```js
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class List2Sample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int list1[] = new int[10];
            int list2[] = new int[10];
            int list3[] = new int[10];
            String input = "";
            int i, x, num = 0, count = 0;
            boolean found = false;
            ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
            
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                { 
                    list1[i] = 0;
                }
                    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                        { 
                            System.out.print("List 1 [" + i + "] : ");
                            try
                                { 
                                    list1[i] = in.nextInt();
                                }
                                
                            catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Error!");
                                }
                        }
            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                { 
                    list2[i] = 0;
                }
                
                    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                        { 
                            System.out.print("List 2 [" + i + "] : ");
                            try
                                { 
                                    list2[i] = in.nextInt();
                                }
                                
                            catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Error!");
                                }
                        }
                        
            System.out.print("list1 : ");
            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print(list1[i] + "\t"); 
                }
            
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("list2 : ");
            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print(list2[i] + "\t"); 
                }
            
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("list3 : ");
            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    list3[0] = list1[0] + list2[0]; list3[1] = list1[1] + list2[1]; list3[2] = list1[2] + list2[2];
                    list3[3] = list1[3] + list2[3]; list3[4] = list1[4] + list2[4]; list3[5] = list1[5] + list2[5];
                    list3[6] = list1[6] + list2[6]; list3[7] = list1[7] + list2[7]; list3[8] = list1[8] + list2[8];
                    list3[9] = list1[9] + list2[9];
                            
                    System.out.print(list3[i] + "\t");
                }
                
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Input value to search in List3: ");
                x = in.nextInt();
                arr.add(list3[0]);
                arr.add(list3[1]);
                arr.add(list3[2]);
                arr.add(list3[3]);
                arr.add(list3[4]);
                arr.add(list3[5]);
                arr.add(list3[6]);
                arr.add(list3[7]);
                arr.add(list3[8]);
                arr.add(list3[9]);

                for (int n : list3)
                    {
                        if (n == x)
                            {
                                found = true;
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        if (list3[i] == x)
                        {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    
                for (Integer value : arr)
                    {}   
                int pos = arr.indexOf(x);
                
                if(found)
                    System.out.println("The value " + x + " is in List3!");
                else
                    System.out.println("The value " + x + " is in List3!");
                    
                System.out.println("There are " + count + " of it in List 3.");
                System.out.println("Located at: " + pos);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code in your question

Comment: @tgdavies hi, thanks for reminding. i have edited my post and include my code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming list3 is an list of integers then using java8 streams

```
    String locations=IntStream.range(0,list3.size())
                           .filter(i->list3.get(i)==userInput)
                           .map(index->"list3["+index+"]")
                           .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

    Int occurences=locations.split(","). length;

    if(occurences>0){System.out.println(userInput +"occurred" + occurences +" Times +" at locations "+locations);}
   else{System.out.println(userInput +"Was not found");}
```

Comment: i have edited my post and included my code. i'm using like java6, should it be compatible with my code?

Comment: java streams was introduced from 7 onwards . I'm afraid you have to upgrade

Answer (score -1):

[`indexOf(ch)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) will only return the first appearance of the value in the array, if you want, you could supplement a second parameter to tell Java where to start looking for the character, like this: [`indexOf(ch, fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,int)).

However, in your case, it's much easier to just use an index based loop to loop through all elements in the array, then record the positions if you found matching characters, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ // loop through all indices of the array, starting from 0, end at arr.length - 1
    if(arr[i] == ch){ // arr[i] is each character in the array at index i, ch is the target character you're matching against
        System.out.println("Character found at position " + i);
    }
}
```